# R and Java have different architectures? How do i determine that?

Tags: java, r

rJava has been loaded successfully and is included in my R library. What does having different architectures mean? Please see error messages below.

```
> library(glmulti)
Loading required package: rJava
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: No CurrentVersion entry in Software/JavaSoft registry! Try re-installing Java and make sure R and Java have matching architectures.
Error: package ‘rJava’ could not be loaded

> install.packages("rJava")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/mmsta/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://mirrors.nics.utk.edu/cran/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/rJava_0.9-11.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 828770 bytes (809 KB)
downloaded 809 KB
package ‘rJava’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
The downloaded binary packages are in
        C:\Users\mmsta\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpg7S7Sh\downloaded_packages

> library(rJava)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: No CurrentVersion entry in Software/JavaSoft registry! Try re-installing Java and make sure R and Java have matching architectures.
> 
> library(glmulti)
Loading required package: rJava
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: No CurrentVersion entry in Software/JavaSoft registry! Try re-installing Java and make sure R and Java have matching architectures.
Error: package ‘rJava’ could not be loaded
```

Thanks. MM

Comment: Probably one is a 32-bit installation and the other a 64-bit installation.

Comment: Bob,  I am thinking about your reply. I could have rJava installed as 32-bit app and glmulti installed as a 64-bit app or vice versa. This time I installed only 64-bit version of R. How would you recommend I deal with this (what changes would you recommend?). Thanks. MM

Comment: How can I determine whether an app is written for 32 or 64-bit applications?

Answer (score 3):

To get the R architecture run `R.Version()$arch`, to get your Java version run `java -version`. For me that yields:

```
R> R.Version()$arch
[1] "x86_64"
R>
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_144"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)
```

The number after `_` in R needs to match the number before `-Bit` in the java output.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Bob Jansen.

It actually turned out easier than expected. I checked for 64-bit versions of windows, chrome, R and java. Then after uninstalling the 32-bit version of JAVA which is at the top of the JAVA download page, I installed the 64-bit version of JAVA found at the bottom of the JAVA install website. This is what is meant by matching architectures.

I was too quick to ask further questions. It is important to always search the web with the error message you are having difficulty with.

MM